# Logging in pyspark using slf4j

Tags: logging, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to write log files from spark into a local file. I have enabled logging in log4j.properties file but it still throws the error:

SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".

SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation

SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.